# Synonymizing license, licence, legal and copyright tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Seems to me it would help with being able to locate general "legal"-type questions if these tags were to be synonyms. This was prompted by my perceived need to add these tags to this recent question: [How is the legal situation for edited maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49174/how-is-the-legal-situation-for-edited-maps)

- [legal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal)
- [copyright](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright)
- [license](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license)

  - [licence](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) should also be synonym of [license](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) or vice-versa

Are there any other similar tags that might also be considered to be synonyms? Or is there a justifiably significant difference between the meanings of these tags?

BTW, I cannot suggest tag synonyms for any of these since I do not have the 5 reputation needed for each tag.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to post a new question about making [licence](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) (8 questions) a synonym of [license](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) (63 questions) when your question was suggested to me as an "already asked".

I agree that [legal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) (13 questions), [copyright](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) (6 questions) and [licence](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) should all be made synonyms of [license](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license).